# Adding terms and condition pages at the end of the crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

i'm still new in crystal reports so i need some help.

I have to add terms and conditions which is 2 pages long at the end of report.How to do that?

I have used report footer but the problem is that report footer gets printed along with group header .

How to add the terms and conditions as two full  pages at the end of report?

Problem: The formatting gridlines & boxes from the order form carries over and I don't know how to suppress those so I just have text on a blank page. Image attached.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg6sy.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should achieve what you want by checking the option `New Page Before` on the report footer section.

Like this, page break is done before the report footer is printed.

Comment: is there any formula i can put to hide bracket on page header ?

Comment: @hafi7_cr7 Not sure what you mean exactly. Maybe [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362050/repeating-row-on-each-page/46362573#46362573) can give some hints for this question. But if your original question is answered, mark this one as answered and create a new question.