# Repeating row on each page

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report consisting of 9 pages (1-9).

I have only one field(String) where I show a record from the database(say amount). The issue is that amount is being displayed on every page. I want that one record (amount) to be shown only on the first page.

I tried several things with formula editing like "Suppress if duplicate" etc.

Page 1/9 of the report:
[image: Page 1/9 of the report]

Page 2/9 of the report:
[image: Page 2/9 of the report]

Note: **Remittance information** is a group header

Comment: In which section is the field placed...page header?

Comment: Details section.

Comment: Means you only want to show the very first record of Details section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your report one of the following formulas should do the trick.

Put inside the suppressing formula of the `amount`-field:

**Number 1**

```
//suppressing the field on all records except the first record 
If OnFirstRecord Then False Else True
```

**Number 2**

```
//suppressing the field on all pages except page 1
If PageNumber=1 Then False Else True
```

**Number 3**

```
//suppressing the field on all groups except #1
If GroupNumber=1 Then False Else True
```

Comment: I used number 2 formula and it worked. This is when I have one amount but what if there are such amounts that I need more than one page to display them all? Will this cause any problem? (sorry for extending this issue too long but today is the very first time dealing with crystal report)

Comment: Yes this will cause problems. What's the condition they should be shown or not? Depending on the answer to this question you should be able to create a formula to suppress them or not...

Comment: I want to show all amounts but the issue was that same amount was repeated on other pages. On the screenshots attached you can see "Gp remittance test1" displayed on two pages which means is a duplicate. All amounts should be shown once(whether is one or more).

Comment: I think that you're on the wrong path. A record is shown more than once if you have joined other tables which are causing the record to be repeated. To handle this you have to create the neccesary groups inside the report.